# Is the RDFa copy mechanism supported by Google?

Tags: html, google-rich-snippets, rdfa

I want to use the RDFa copy mechanism in some structured data for a web page.

Here is an example of what I'm trying to do (this is not a complete example but demonstrates the problem I am having):

```html
    <div vocab="http://schema.org/">
        <div resource="#muse" typeof="rdfa:Pattern">
            <link property="image" href="Muse1.jpg"/>
            <link property="image" href="Muse2.jpg"/>
            <link property="image" href="Muse3.jpg"/>
            <span property="name">Muse</span>
        </div>
        <p typeof="MusicEvent">
            <link property="rdfa:copy" href="#muse"/>
            Muse at the United Center.
            <time property="startDate" datetime="2013-03-03">March 3rd 2013</time>, 
            <a property="location" href="#united">United Center, Chicago, Illinois</a>
        </p>
        <p typeof="MusicEvent">
            <link property="rdfa:copy" href="#muse"/>
            Muse at the Target Center.
            <time property="startDate" datetime="2013-03-07">March 7th 2013</time>, 
            <a property="location" href="#target">Target Center, Minneapolis, Minnesota</a>
        </p>
    </div>
```

When I try to validate this using Google's Structured Data Testing Tool, I keep getting two different errors for the link copy tag:

> The property `http://www.w3.org/ns/rdfa#copy` is not recognized by Google for an object of type `MusicEvent`
>
> The type `http://www.w3.org/ns/rdfa#Pattern` is not a type known to Google.

The properties included by the copy are listed and validate properly.  But I'm not sure what is causing these errors and if it will mean that Google ignores my structured data altogether.  Am I doing something wrong?  Does Google not support using the copy mechanism?  Or maybe this is just one of those cases where the Structured Data Testing Tool is incomplete but there won't be any problems when my page is actually indexed?

Comment: From my experience, the testing tool won't recognize very well properties outside the schema.org vocabulary. Frankly, I have switched from rdf-a annotations to json-ld snippets, which are easier to maintain.